# How to use localized categories properly?

Tags: localization, relations, category

I've setup a localized site (de/en) with custom routing for my categories (which are marked as translatable). I use a *tag route* for my categories which points to the same template as my structure. Everything seemed to work fine but then I realized that the custom filter (via relatedTo) also outputs entries that don't belong to the current category locale.

To make it clear I'll try to give a rough schemata of my setup (using Craft Pro 2.3.2640):

**section** *projects*:

```
has the entry url format:
  de -> projekte/{slug}    
  en -> projects/{slug}
entry template path:
  projects/_entry
```

**single** *projectsIndex*:

```
has the entry url format:
  de -> projekte  
  en -> projects
entry template path:
  projects/index
```

**routes**:

```
de -> projekte/(tag)
  template path: projects/index
en -> projects/(tag)
  template path: projects/index
```

**category**:

```
doesn't have a it's own url
category field is marked as translatable
```

**category entries** (german version and the english translation):

```
 - de -> kultur      en -> culture    | (resp. title and slug)
 - de -> industrie   en -> industry   | (resp. title and slug)
 ...
```

**project entries**:

```
 - Entry A:
     de -> category relations ['industrie', 'kultur']
     en -> category relations ['industry']
 - Entry B:
     de -> category relations ['kultur']
     en -> category relations ['culture']
```

**template projects/index.html**:

```
...
{% set _filter = tag|default(null) %}
{% set _category = craft.categories.slug(_filter) %}
...
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('projects').relatedTo(_category) %}
   ...
```

**urls** (here comes the trouble):

```
 - /projekte
     -> lists german version of 'Entry A' and 'Entry B'  (expected)
 - /en/projects
     -> lists english version of 'Entry A' and 'Entry B' (expected)

 - /projekte/kultur
     -> lists german version of 'Entry A' and 'Entry B'  (expected)
 - /en/projects/culture
     -> lists english version of 'Entry A' (NOT expected) and 'Entry B'
```

...'Entry A' on '/en/projects/culture' shouldn't show up just because there's the 'kultur' category attached to the german version of this entry!

I already tried to explicitly restrict the '_category' by using the '.locale' method but that didn't help either. Now I wonder if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong or if this is a bug by craft itself.

Any tips are appreciated.

Thanks

**Update:** 
Answering my own question [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/8957/3323).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer my own question see below:

As [carlcs](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/users/125/carlcs) pointed out correctly the problem actually isn't located in getting the category - which works just well and is the right way to do it - but in how the relation to the entries is done.

1. I should check if the tag (coming from the url) actually resolves to a "real" category, otherwise just all entries will be shown.
2. just handling over the category to the `.relatedTo` method on craft.entries won't do it because that just fetches all entries related to this category irrespective to its locale - `sourceLocale: craft.locale` needs to be set.
3. Still not finished; because we want to "*find elements related to the given element, where the given element is the target of the relation*" – target in this sense is the category – we need to define it as `tagetElement` in the `relatedTo` method.

...

Getting the entries should now look like this:

```
{% if categories|length %}
    {% set entries = 
              craft.entries.section('projects').relatedTo({
                 targetElement: categories,
                 sourceLocale: craft.locale
              }) 
    %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
    ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

...

And the actual title of my question should be **"How to do category relations with locales"** ;)

Comment: Nice catch with that `sourceLocale` parameter! Setting `targetElement` is probably not necessary, `element` should do it if there's no other relations between these elements.

Answer (score 2):

An elements `slug` property is saved per locale, so you shouldn't get categories with a slug "culture" in your german locale. The `locale` property is set to your current locale by default, so there's no need to set that explicitly.

I just did a simple test to see if there's no exception to category ElementCriteriaModels.

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.slug('alkoholfrei') %}
{{ categories|length ? categories.first().title }}
```

And I can confirm it works as expected, a category with a translated german slug of "alkoholfrei" is not returned in other locales.

<s>I would recommend to double check your category slugs, you probably only translated the title and your slug is not yet updated.</s>

But the actual problem with your code is not how you get the categories, but how you're dealing with them in the `craft.entries` ElementCriteriaModel. You should check if there's actually categories found, because otherwise your `relatedTo` param doesn't do anything and you simple get all your "project" entries returned.

```
{% if categories|length %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.section('projects').relatedTo(categories) %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I just double checked - the slug's are translated for sure. Outputting the categories slug (and title); on the english page I get `culture` and on the german page I get `kultur`. Getting the right category doesn't seem the problem ... It looks more like the issues is with the `relatedTo` method not distinguishing between the locales of the category?!

Comment: Ahhh, now I think I know where the mistake is, will edit the answer...

Comment: I've oversimplified the code to be more clear ... actually I do check if there where categories found. Anyway ... I think I found the answer, which has to do setting targetElement and locale explicitly in relatedTo. ... I'll submit a separate answer.